# image display using Arra.map in reactnative

Tags: react-native

I am getting image path like this using  {chatBoxMessages.image_server}

```
  :  file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/IMG_20180810_090500.JPG
```

how can i display the image using the above path .

i am trying `<Image source={{uri : 'http://10.42.0.1:8000{chatBoxMessages.image_server}'}} style={{ width: 150, height: 100}}/>` this image Tag but image was not displaying .

Please help me for displaying image

```
 this.state.chatMesages.map(function(chatBoxMessages, index){

            return(

              <View>


                 <Text style={styles.messagesRightContainer} key={index}>

                <Image source={{uri : 'http://10.42.0.1:8000{chatBoxMessages.image_server}'}} style={{ width: 150, height: 100}}/>

</Text>


            </View>
             )

                  })
```

Comment: For check that is URL is correct or not. you can print the URL in the Text like this 
                 <Text >http://10.42.0.1:8000{chatBoxMessages.image_server}</Text>

and anyhow directly open it the browser.

and other thing is. you should not use http://10.42.0.1:8000 url.
Use direct folder path if image is present inside the project directory

Comment: log the value for * chatBoxMessages.image_server * and what is exactly value is.